# How to connect to a JanusGraph with dynamodb backend using Java Client Code?

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am trying to build a Java application which uses JanusGraph(with dynamodb backend) which is hosted on a remote machine and has gremlin server started.

I want to know what my options are when writing a client for this setup!!

1) Any OGM like FERMA. Looks like there is no support.
2) Use gremlin java driver and write the client code using Cluster Class.
3) Anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

**I am the lead developer on Ferma.**

Obviously I am a bit bias but ferma has fairly complete documentation (I hope), and we always respond on gitter and to issues within 24 hours. So support shouldnt be much of a problem.

I havent seen any complete OGM options outside of Ferma but there are a few obsolete projects like totorom, frames, peapod, and similar you may want to look at. I am afraid they will have even less support than ferma though.

To your question, to connect to JanusGraph there are several options depending on the framework you using. You basically configure any options you need in the JanusGraphFactory then connect to the desired host with the following call. Then just pass this graph object into the constructor of a FramedGraph.

Graph graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('cassandra:localhost')

Comment: Thanks for reply jeff. Can get a Remote Graph working with Ferma?

Comment: I was referring to remote graph "support" in my question.

Comment: @SandeepKumarJakkaraju There you go i updated the answer to show how to connect to a remote janus graph instance.